# Does anyone know the source of this video?

Tags: apollo-program, apollo-11, apollo-17

I would like to know the source of this video? I cannot find it on youtube, but I think it's from the Apollo 17 launch (because it's night). Any ideas? Is my Apollo 17 guess correct?

This is the video: https://streamable.com/t6rryb

Comment: The time may be less helpful since the mobile service structure is still in place with arms out and that was moved back a some time prior to launch, a day per http://apollolaunchcontrol.com/v20test/http___www.apollolaunchcontrol.com_/Mobile_Service_Structure.html

Comment: Any idea if this is actually Apollo 17 or something else?

Comment: It could be any of the launches. The rocket does not have any hints of activation - gases leaking out during filling of tanks, etc. Apollo 17 was the only night time launch, launching at 0533 UTC, 0033 local. I doubt the pictures are of Apollo 17 because there are two pictures  that show a pre-dawn glow in the sky - lighter sky & hints of red.

Answer (score 3):

The video is too low in quality to make much of but assuming the clips are not just footage from different times or launches and the move of the mobile service structure between beginning and end actually indicates a launch within 24 hours then it is possible this is Apollo 17 because the moon is still only coming into day, and the landings were timed to be near lunar sunrise for temperature and contrast reasons, and Apollo 17 was the 'newest' of the landings looking at this rendering of moon phase at landing][1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQcuq7oT7ko) for each flight.

It could however have also been any of the non landing flights that launched on a Saturn V (7-10), shot at some other unrelated time peioe to launch day or the time between pre launch footage and actual landing is enough to make estimation of moon phase in fuzzy footage pointless.

If attempting to pin down more closely it might be possible to try computing the actual moon position for each of the shots featuring it along with the schedule for launch preparations but seems fairly pointless for a video of this quality and no certainty they are actually from the same night or even the same launch.

The absence of ice on the LOX tank indicates that the vehicle is not fully fueled and ready, but unsure how long it took for visible ice to form.

All that can really be said is that
It is block II  CSM (silver not white) so not Apollo 1 or unmanned launches.
It is not a Saturn I so not 7, Apollo-Soyuz and the 3 space labs.
Is not Skylab

In terms of what the footage is, they do not look like the engineering cameras that were fixed around the place for launches (carefully framed shots, footage of the lights) and look to be shot inside the pad area itself (so not general media) so most likely some form of PR or documentation cameraman, probably quite some time prior to launch [gathering B-roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-roll).