# Are there any markings that uniquely identify each Saturn-Apollo combination?

Tags: apollo-program, identify-this-object, saturn-v

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54132/does-anyone-know-the-source-of-this-video) made me wonder: are there any markings on the Saturn I/IB/V launch vehicle, Apollo service module or command module that uniquely identify each vehicle (i.e. AS-5xx)?

It doesn't have to be a mission-specific marking; it may also be e.g. an externally visible identification of a stage, the instrument unit, or CSM that can be uniquely linked to a mission. For example, if a particular SI-C stage had a big #6 painted on it, it could be linked to AS-506, which was used in Apollo 11.

I thought that the IU had some white markings on its black exterior that were unique to each unit, but I cannot find a reference for that (so I may have made that up...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The detailed [flight log at apollosaturn.com](https://www.apollosaturn.com/Website/Saturn-V-Flight-History) reports that "exterior markings remained identical for all vehicles" from Apollo 9 onwards.

However, there were still some slight variations, even if the paint markings were the same. For example, they note that [the Saturn II insulation type changed](https://www.apollosaturn.com/Website-II/SII-Second-Stage-Insulation-differences/).

The instrument unit had some more visible differences. These pictures are all taken from approximately the same angle during launch:

- [Apollo 8](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_8_liftoff.jpg)
- [Apollo 9](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo9-launch2-noID.jpg)
- [Apollo 10](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_10_launch.jpg)
- [Apollo 11](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_Launch_-_GPN-2000-000630.jpg)
- [Apollo 12](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_12_launches_from_Kennedy_Space_Center.jpg)
- [Apollo 13](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_13_launch_(S70-34852).jpg)
- [Apollo 14](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_14_launch.jpg)
- [Apollo 16](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_16_Saturn_V_launch.jpg)
- [Apollo 17](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_17_liftoff.jpg)

Apollo 8 and 9 have solid black bands at the top, covering the instrument unit and the top of the third stage; Apollo 10, 11 and 12 have a white patch (I think an access door for the instrument unit); Apollo 13, 14, 16 & 17 have two of these patches (and presumably so did 15?).

For closer inspection, there was at least one visible serial number. It's only just visible in these pictures, but here it is on Apollo 13:

[image]

This is the serial of that particular Saturn IC stage (**S-IC-8**), and seems to have been applied from Apollo 8 onwards.

Comment: Great find! Seems to be censored here, lol https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Ap10-KSC-68C-7912.jpg/1200px-Ap10-KSC-68C-7912.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble how interesting! on the pad that same label seems to have been repainted (it's on the left [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ground-level_view_of_the_Apollo_10_space_vehicle_on_Pad_B.jpg) - note darker background) - I wonder if it got smudged and was reapplied?

Comment: There are also pictures at Michoud of the mostly-painted/assembled units without them as well, which is interesting ([example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Saturn_V_S-1C_Stages_in_Michoud_Assembly_Facility_-_GPN-2000-000048.jpg), [example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Saturn_V_Stage_at_Michould_Assembly_Facility_-_GPN-2000-000042.jpg))

Comment: Maybe they didn't paint the last digit in until it was stacked.

Comment: I've found a lot of pictures where I can see that the label is there, but not read it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble hmm, [here's one](https://images.nasa.gov/details-6869297) (maybe -6?) with the number in place at Michoud during testing, so it seems to have been applied at some point before it was shipped.

Comment: Maybe the last digit isn't applied in that one ?

Comment: Great find indeed!  @OrganicMarble I believe I read somewhere (Stages to Saturn?) that they renamed the stages at some point to make them line up, i.e. AS-508 consists of S-IC-8, S-II-8 and S-IVB-8. That would explain maybe why earlier ones got repainted/relabelled.

Comment: @Ludo There's [a footnote](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/notes.htm#6.55) about this in *Stages to Saturn*, and a longer explanation in the [*Saturn Chronology*](https://history.nasa.gov/MHR-5/part-8.htm) -it seems to have been the S-IVB stages that were renamed - after -503 exploded in tests, -504-6 became -503N-5N, and spare parts for -507 became the new -506. This avoided flying stages with mismatched numbers. Can't find an equivalent change for S-IC, though.

Comment: @Andrew that is indeed the footnote I had in mind, mixed up the stages in my head.